# Implementing Facebook's "Continue As {Name}" using FB Web API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to implement the Facebook "Continue as {Name}" feature as described on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/

However, my current implementation does not use the `<div class="fb-login-button" ...></div>` method as shown in that page.  I login using the FB SDK manually.  I would like to keep this implementation if possible.

My question is: is it possible to retrieve the users' name without asking for permission from my app?

Comment: No, that is not possible. The plugin itself renders inside an iframe, thereby keeping you from accessing this information. Anything else, that uses your own button, would have to give you access to this information, but since it of course is none of your business ...

Comment: @CBroe Thought so.  Thanks!